# Changing font in tabular

Tags: tables, fonts, verbatim

I desperately need someone's help. 
For the past hour I was trying to perform a task so diabolically difficult, even the Hercules himself couldn't achieve: change the freaking font in a table.

My table looks something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.14\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.62\textwidth}|} \hline
something & something & something wider\\
lather & rinse & repeat \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I want this table to be in verbatim font. I tried putting the whole tabular in `texttt{ }`,
but it generates over `9000 badboxes` in Kile. Why ? Beats me, it looks fine. Putting the whole table in

```
\begin{verbatim} 
\end{verbatim}
```

doesn't work.

Then I found that you can set the font of a column:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\ttfamily}p{0.14\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.62\textwidth}|} \hline
```

And you know what? It actually worked! The first column was in verbatim. So, I tried the second one

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\ttfamily}p{0.14\textwidth}|>{\ttfamily}p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.62\textwidth}|} \hline
```

and it worked too! I tried it with the last one

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\ttfamily}p{0.14\textwidth}|>{\ttfamily}p{0.12\textwidth}|>{\ttfamily}p{0.62\textwidth}|} \hline
```

and that of course generates badboxes. I'm *that* close to success, and the pesky LaTeX has to make problems. I've read that you could set up a whole new environment to change the font, which, frankly, seems too excessive to do.

So, how can I achieve what I want to achieve, without turning the whole world upside-down ?

Comment: You probably want `\ttfamily\raggedright\arraybackslash`

Comment: Oh god. It worked. Tell me, master, what do the \raggedright\arraybackslash do? I tried it without \raggedright, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can also put `{\ttfamily\selectfont <your tabular> }` around your tabular to change the font of the document temporarily. But don't take TeX too seriously sometimes it just likes to mess with your mind. Just keep shouting *Not my problem* when you see bad box warnings but no visual problems.

Comment: @percusse `\selectfont` is redundant

Answer (score 15):

Narrow columns are always difficult to typeset with justification that, on the other hand, makes little sense with typewriter type.

So we can add `\raggedright` to avoid justification: it'll make the text in the cell flush to the left margin, but not with the right margin.

Thus you can do

```
\begin{tabular}{
  |>{\ttfamily\raggedright}p{0.14\textwidth}
  |>{\ttfamily\raggedright}p{0.12\textwidth}
  |>{\ttfamily\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.62\textwidth}
  |}
\hline
...
\end{tabular}
```

The `\arraybackslash` in the last column specification is needed because otherwise you can't end the row with `\\` (`\raggedright` redefines it). See the manual of the `array` package.

If all the tabular is to be typeset in typewriter type, also adding a `\ttfamily` declaration before it and protected in a group could do, but I believe that this way is better, since it allows more flexibility; for instance you could want to add a new column with different type.